# Getting the RATE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED in bitly

Tags: php, bit.ly

can any one tell me why i am getting this error .I am using the bit.ly to share in twitter.Sometimes i am getting the error

{"errorCode": 403, "errorMessage": "RATE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED", "results": null, "statusCode": ""} Bit.ly "

Comment: Here are some hints: http://code.google.com/p/bitly-api/wiki/ApiDocumentation#Rate_Limiting

Answer (score 4):

Here check the bitly best practices to avoid such an error Message.

[bitly rate limitation best practices](http://code.google.com/p/bitly-api/wiki/ApiBestPractices)

How much URLs are u trying to shorten per hour?